# JavaScript - Sort list by object property value

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a list like so:

```
var list = [{
    title: 'Green',
    data: {
      test: 'world'
    }
  }, {
    title: 'Blue',
    data: {
      test: 'world'
    }
  }, {
    title: 'Red',
    data: {
      test: 'world'
    }
  }];
```

and I have a simple array like this: `var orderList = ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue']`.

How would I make it so anytime the `list` array gets created (and its random) for then for it to be sorted by the order of which `orderBy` goes? So, if an array item's `title` is `Red`... it gets put at top and if it's `Green`... it goes below the `Red` object.

**Edit:** This is NOT sorting A-Z because I want to list it from the order the `orderList` is on.

The problem happens when the user selected, let's say, `Green`, well.. it should be first but for some reason, I get `null, Green` or something like that.

```js
var randomBtn = document.querySelector('.random');
var orderIt = document.querySelector('.orderIt');
var selectedList = document.querySelector('.selectedList');
var orderedList = document.querySelector('.orderedList');

orderIt.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  orderBy(list);
});


  var list = [{
    title: 'Green',
    data: {
      test: 'world'
    }
  }, {
    title: 'Blue',
    data: {
      test: 'world'
    }
  }];
  
  selectedList.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(list, null, 4)
  var orderList = ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue'];


  var orderBy = function(list) {

    var tempArr = [];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      var getItem = list.filter(function(e) {
        return e.title === orderList[i];
      })[0];
      tempArr.push(getItem);
    }
    
    orderedList.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(tempArr, null, 4);
    
  }
```

```html
<button class='orderIt'>Order by Heiarchy</button>
<br /><br />
<pre class='selectedList'></pre>

Ordered List: must always be RED, GREEN, BLUE.
<pre class='orderedList'></pre>
```

Comment: keep questions to only what is relevant... the shuffle vs ordered is confusing. The fact that is already shuffled doesn't seem relevant to what you are asking ... so the shuffle code is irrelevant (I think)

Comment: do you want it ascending or descending?

Comment: @funcoding That shouldn't matter because the order is based on the `orderList` so `red`... should always be first... `green` should always be last.

Comment: @charlietfl The shuffle is just to shuffle the array for demo purposes. Not realted. The order is what I'd like to finalize. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: I thought you want it sort it by the list array?

Comment: @funcoding Nope. It needs to sort by whats in order from `orderList` is. So `red` is first...then take whatever object's `title` is red... and make it first... and on and on.

Comment: and that's my point... the shuffle is irrelevant to the problem you are asking about. For better explanation see [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl Alright, I'll fix this. Give me a minute.

Comment: try this `list.sort((a,b) => orderList.indexOf(a.title) - orderList.indexOf(b.title));
  console.log(list)`

Comment: @charlietfl That worked. Whoa. Thank you, charlietfl. I never knew about the `-` in the `sort` function. I'll have to read more about it. I made it waaaay to complicated.

Comment: only works for numerical values